# Min Max and Mean as new columns Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have the following dataframe:

```
distros = ['distro_1', 'distro_1', 'distro_1', 'distro_2', 'distro_2', 'distro_2']
tco = [110, 110, 111, 109, 109, 108]
tang = [77, 77, 76, 81, 80, 80]

velocities = {'distro': distros, 'tco': tco, 'tang': tang}

df_velocities = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(velocities)
```

I need columns with the minimum, maximum and average values ​​of each column for each distro value.

I believe it is possible to do this using the agg function. I'm not getting. I am following the documentation of Pandas and the result is by line.

What I have is

[image]

Any tips?

What I need is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df_velocities = df_velocities.groupby('distro').agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])

print(df_velocities)
          tco                  tang               
          min  max        mean  min max       mean
distro                                            
distro_1  110  111  110.333333   76  77  76.666667
distro_2  108  109  108.666667   80  81  80.333333

df_velocities.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df_velocities.columns]
#df_velocities.columns = df_velocities.columns.map('_'.join)
df_velocities = df_velocities.reset_index()

print(df_velocities)
     distro  tco_min  tco_max    tco_mean  tang_min  tang_max  tang_mean
0  distro_1      110      111  110.333333        76        77  76.666667
1  distro_2      108      109  108.666667        80        81  80.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
df_aggregated = df_velocities.groupby('distro').agg({'tco': ['mean', 'min', 'max'], 'tang': ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

Comment: It's ok too. But, my dataframe has a lot of features. Here is only an exemple. So, for me, the first one is better. Thank you very much.